# Why does the F# type provider for JSON appear to be wrapping strings in an extra pair of quotation marks?

Tags: f#, f#-data

One of the fields in the JSON I'm parsing with the type provider evaluates to the type BooleanOrString. The JSON is field is called value. The JSON Parse operation is successful. When I get the string value from this field using json.Value.ToString(), the string value that is returned is wrapped in 2 pairs of double quotes instead of 1.

I can trim these out as a work around. Is there some other option for extracting the string values that may not have this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that `ToString` is returning a JSON-formatted representation of the value and when you call that from F# Interactive, this appears as doubly-quoted string.

The example I tried using is this:

```
#r "nuget:FSharp.Data"
open FSharp.Data

type T = JsonProvider<"""[{"value":true}, {"value":"whatever"}]""">

let v0 = T.GetSamples().[0]
let v1 = T.GetSamples().[1]
```

If I access `v1.Value.ToString()` in F# interactive, I get:

```
> val it: string = ""whatever""
```

However, the value itself has just single quote (`printfn $"{v1.Value}"` prints just `"whatever"`) and this is a JSON-representation of the string (if you could have top-level strings in JSON).

A better way of accessing the value than using `Value.ToString()` is to pattern-match:

```
for v in T.GetSamples() do
  match v.Value.String, v.Value.Boolean with
  | Some s, _ -> printfn $"It is a string: {s}"
  | _, Some b -> printfn $"It is a bool: {b}"
```

In this way, there are no extra quotes anywhere.